# How to share variables across scripts in python?

Tags: python, variables, share

The following does not work

one.py

```
import shared
shared.value = 'Hello'
raw_input('A cheap way to keep process alive..')
```

two.py

```
import shared
print shared.value
```

run on two command lines as:

```
>>python one.py
>>python two.py
```

(the second one gets an attribute error, rightly so).

Is there a way to accomplish this, that is, share a variable between two scripts?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to share a value over two totally separate python sessions? If so, that's not possible by just setting a value in a shared module.

Comment: Thank you. 
For now what I am doing is creating a third module that imports both so that everything happens in the same session. The pickle solution does not quite work for me because I was looking at setting a threading.Condition() variable in one module (which is not picklable because of the implied lock), and using it from both sessions. And now I think about it, being able to share the variable is probably the least of my problems as I don't think the state in the condition variable is going to be shared.

Comment: I got to this question when I had the same problem. Then I read about sockets. Why not use them?

Answer (score 59):

Hope it's OK to jot down my notes about this issue here.

First of all, I appreciate the example in the OP a lot, because that is where I started as well - although it made me think `shared` is some built-in Python module, until I found a complete example at [[Tutor] Global Variables between Modules ??](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-November/018353.html).

However, when I looked for "sharing variables between scripts" (or processes) - besides the case when a Python script needs to use variables defined in other Python source files (but not necessarily running processes) - I mostly stumbled upon two other use cases:

- A script forks itself into multiple child processes, which then run in parallel (possibly on multiple processors) on the same PC
- A script spawns multiple other child processes, which then run in parallel (possibly on multiple processors) on the same PC

As such, most hits regarding "shared variables" and "interprocess communication" (IPC) discuss cases like these two; however, in both of these cases one can observe a "parent", to which the "children" usually have a reference.

What I am interested in, however, is running multiple invocations of the same script, ran independently, and sharing data between those (as in [Python: how to share an object instance across multiple invocations of a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481602/)), in a singleton/single instance mode. That kind of problem is not really addressed by the above two cases - instead, it essentially reduces to the example in OP (sharing variables across two scripts).

Now, when dealing with this problem in Perl, there is [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Shareable); which "allows you to tie a variable to shared memory", using "an integer number or 4 character string[1] that serves as a common identifier for data across process space". Thus, there are no temporary files, nor networking setups - which I find great for my use case; so I was looking for the same in Python.

However, as [accepted answer by @Drewfer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829270/277826) notes: "*You're not going to be able to do what you want without storing the information somewhere external to the two instances of the interpreter*"; or in other words: either you have to use a networking/socket setup - or you have to use temporary files (ergo, no shared RAM for "*totally separate python sessions*").

Now, even with these considerations, it is kinda difficult to find working examples (except for `pickle`) - also in the docs for [mmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) and [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). I have managed to find some other examples - which also describe some pitfalls that the docs do not mention:

- Usage of `mmap`: working code in two different scripts at [Sharing Python data between processes using mmap | schmichael's blog](http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/)

  - Demonstrates how both scripts change the shared value
  - Note that here a temporary file is created as storage for saved data - `mmap` is just a special interface for accessing this temporary file
- Usage of `multiprocessing`: working code at:

  - [Python multiprocessing RemoteManager under a multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550506/277826) - working example of `SyncManager` (via `manager.start()`) with shared `Queue`; server(s) writes, clients read (shared data)
  - [Comparison of the multiprocessing module and pyro?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955757/277826) - working example of `BaseManager` (via `server.serve_forever()`) with shared custom class; server writes, client reads and writes
  - [How to synchronize a python dict with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556974/277826) - this answer has a great explanation of `multiprocessing` pitfalls, and is a working example of `SyncManager` (via `manager.start()`) with shared dict; server does nothing, client reads and writes

Thanks to these examples, I came up with an example, which essentially does the same as the `mmap` example, with approaches from the "*synchronize a python dict*" example - using `BaseManager` (via `manager.start()` through file path address) with shared list; both server and client read and write (pasted below). Note that:

- `multiprocessing` managers can be started either via `manager.start()` or `server.serve_forever()`

  - `serve_forever()` locks - `start()` doesn't
  - There is auto-logging facility in `multiprocessing`: it seems to work fine with `start()`ed processes - but seems to ignore the ones that `serve_forever()`
- The address specification in `multiprocessing` can be IP (socket) or temporary file (possibly a pipe?) path; in `multiprocessing` docs:

  - Most examples  use `multiprocessing.Manager()` - this is just a function (*not* class instantiation) which returns a `SyncManager`, which is a special subclass of `BaseManager`; and uses `start()` - but *not* for IPC between independently ran scripts; here a file path is used
  - Few other examples `serve_forever()` approach for IPC between independently ran scripts; here IP/socket address is used
  - If an address is not specified, then an temp file path is used automatically (see [16.6.2.12. Logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging) for an example of how to see this)

In addition to all the pitfalls in the "*synchronize a python dict*" post, there are additional ones in case of a list. That post notes:

> All manipulations of the dict must be done with methods and not dict assignments (syncdict["blast"] = 2 will fail miserably because of the way multiprocessing shares custom objects)

The workaround to `dict['key']` getting and setting, is the use of the `dict` public methods `get` and `update`. The problem is that there are no such public methods as alternative for `list[index]`; thus, for a shared list, in addition we have to register `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods (which are private for `list`) as `exposed`, which means we also have to re-register all the public methods for `list` as well `:/`

Well, I think those were the most critical things; these are the two scripts - they can just be ran in separate terminals (server first); note developed on Linux with Python 2.7:

`a.py` (server):

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers

import logging
logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class MyListManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass


syncarr = []
def get_arr():
    return syncarr

def main():

    # print dir([]) # cannot do `exposed = dir([])`!! manually:
    MyListManager.register("syncarr", get_arr, exposed=['__getitem__', '__setitem__', '__str__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort'])

    manager = MyListManager(address=('/tmp/mypipe'), authkey='')
    manager.start()

    # we don't use the same name as `syncarr` here (although we could);
    # just to see that `syncarr_tmp` is actually <AutoProxy[syncarr] object>
    # so we also have to expose `__str__` method in order to print its list values!
    syncarr_tmp = manager.syncarr()
    print("syncarr (master):", syncarr, "syncarr_tmp:", syncarr_tmp)
    print("syncarr initial:", syncarr_tmp.__str__())

    syncarr_tmp.append(140)
    syncarr_tmp.append("hello")

    print("syncarr set:", str(syncarr_tmp))

    raw_input('Now run b.py and press ENTER')

    print
    print 'Changing [0]'
    syncarr_tmp.__setitem__(0, 250)

    print 'Changing [1]'
    syncarr_tmp.__setitem__(1, "foo")

    new_i = raw_input('Enter a new int value for [0]: ')
    syncarr_tmp.__setitem__(0, int(new_i))

    raw_input("Press any key (NOT Ctrl-C!) to kill server (but kill client first)".center(50, "-"))
    manager.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

`b.py` (client)

```
import time

import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers

import logging
logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class MyListManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass

MyListManager.register("syncarr")

def main():
  manager = MyListManager(address=('/tmp/mypipe'), authkey='')
  manager.connect()
  syncarr = manager.syncarr()

  print "arr = %s" % (dir(syncarr))

  # note here we need not bother with __str__ 
  # syncarr can be printed as a list without a problem:
  print "List at start:", syncarr
  print "Changing from client"
  syncarr.append(30)
  print "List now:", syncarr

  o0 = None
  o1 = None

  while 1:
    new_0 = syncarr.__getitem__(0) # syncarr[0]
    new_1 = syncarr.__getitem__(1) # syncarr[1]

    if o0 != new_0 or o1 != new_1:
      print 'o0: %s => %s' % (str(o0), str(new_0))
      print 'o1: %s => %s' % (str(o1), str(new_1))
      print "List is:", syncarr

      print 'Press Ctrl-C to exit'
      o0 = new_0
      o1 = new_1

    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As a final remark, on Linux `/tmp/mypipe` is created - but is 0 bytes, and has attributes `srwxr-xr-x` (for a socket); I guess this makes me happy, as I neither have to worry about network ports, nor about temporary files as such `:)`

Other related questions:

- [Python: Possible to share in-memory data between 2 separate processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269055/277826) (very good explanation)
- [Efficient Python to Python IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839786/efficient-python-to-python-ipc)
- [Python: Sending a variable to another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066126/python-sending-a-variable-to-another-script)

Answer (score 26):

You're not going to be able to do what you want without storing the information somewhere external to the two instances of the interpreter.
If it's just simple variables you want, you can easily dump a python dict to a file with the pickle module in script one and then re-load it in script two.
Example:

one.py

```
import pickle

shared = {"Foo":"Bar", "Parrot":"Dead"}
fp = open("shared.pkl","w")
pickle.dump(shared, fp)
```

two.py

```
import pickle

fp = open("shared.pkl")
shared = pickle.load(fp)
print shared["Foo"]
```

Comment: Similar approach I used. Instead of pickle I am storing the variable value in text file. Any idea which is better text or pickle file ?

Comment: It will not work for data coming via event streams because I do not know how to figure out how much data already processed.

Comment: I have one program which may write into such a file and several which may read it. Does anyone have proof that these programs are not disturbing each other if they try to read, write at the exact same moment?

Comment: Wouldn't be there a race condition if the processes try to write into the file at the same time?

Answer (score 20):

```sh
sudo apt-get install memcached python-memcache
```

one.py

```py
import memcache
shared = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
shared.set('Value', 'Hello')
```

two.py

```py
import memcache
shared = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)    
print shared.get('Value')
```

Comment: is it possible to use your solution with complex object such as APScheduler objetcs?

Comment: What package did you use for memcache?

Comment: @Hamed pymemcached

Comment: `sudo python3 -m pip install python-memcached`. Passing 'localhost' to Client will result in error, use 127.0.0.1. Everything else works fine @ 2020.

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to do here (store a shared state in a Python module over separate python interpreters) won't work.

A value in a module can be updated by one module and then read by another module, but this must be within the same Python interpreter. What you seem to be doing here is actually a sort of interprocess communication; this could be accomplished via socket communication between the two processes, but it is significantly less trivial than what you are expecting to have work here.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the relative simple mmap file.
you can use the shared.py to store the common constants. The following code will work across different python interpreters \ scripts \processes

shared.py:

```
MMAP_SIZE = 16*1024 
MMAP_NAME = 'Global\\SHARED_MMAP_NAME'
```

* The "Global" is windows syntax for global names

one.py:

```
from shared import MMAP_SIZE,MMAP_NAME                                                        
def write_to_mmap():                                                                          
    map_file = mmap.mmap(-1,MMAP_SIZE,tagname=MMAP_NAME,access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)             
    map_file.seek(0)                                                                          
    map_file.write('hello\n')                                                                 
    ret = map_file.flush() != 0                                                               
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):                                                        
        assert(ret != 0)                                                                      
    else:                                                                                     
        assert(ret == 0)
```

two.py:

```
from shared import MMAP_SIZE,MMAP_NAME                                          
def read_from_mmap():                                                           
    map_file = mmap.mmap(-1,MMAP_SIZE,tagname=MMAP_NAME,access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    map_file.seek(0)                                                            
    data = map_file.readline().rstrip('\n')                                     
    map_file.close()                                                            
    print data
```

*This code was written for windows, linux might need little adjustments

more info at - https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 6):

#### Share a dynamic variable by `Redis`:

script_one.py

```
from redis import Redis
from time import sleep

cli = Redis('localhost')
shared_var = 1

while True:
   cli.set('share_place', shared_var)
   shared_var += 1
   sleep(1)
```

Run *script_one* in a terminal (a process):

```
$ python script_one.py
```

---

script_two.py

```
from redis import Redis
from time import sleep

cli = Redis('localhost')

while True:
    print(int(cli.get('share_place')))
    sleep(1)
```

Run *script_two* in another terminal (another process):

```
$ python script_two.py
```

Out:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

---

Dependencies:

```
$ pip install redis
$ apt-get install redis-server
```

Comment: What if you would want to share the **redis connection pool** between two command line processes?

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise that you use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.  You can't run two scripts from the commandline, but you can have two separate processes easily speak to each other.

From the doc's examples:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

Comment: I just posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14700365/277826), where two scripts are ran from the command line, and use `multiprocessing` to share variables.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the variable in some sort of persistent file.  There are several modules to do this, depending on your exact need.

The pickle and cPickle module can save and load most python objects to file.

The shelve module can store python objects in a dictionary-like structure (using pickle behind the scenes).

The dbm/bsddb/dbhash/gdm modules can store string variables in a dictionary-like structure.

The sqlite3 module can store data in a lightweight SQL database.

The biggest problem with most of these are that they are not synchronised across different processes - if one process reads a value while another is writing to the datastore then you may get incorrect data or data corruption.  To get round this you will need to write your own file locking mechanism or use a full-blown database.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna **read and modify shared data** between 2 scripts which run separately, a good solution would be to take advantage of python multiprocessing module and use a [Pipe() or a Queue()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) (see differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463008/multiprocessing-pipe-vs-queue/58015119#58015119)). This way you get to sync scripts and avoid problems regarding concurrency and global variables (like what happens if both scripts wanna modify a variable at the same time).

The best part about using pipes/queues is that you can pass python objects through them.

Also there are methods to avoid waiting for data if there hasn't been passed yet ([queue.empty()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty) and [pipeConn.poll()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll)).

See an example using Queue() below:

```py
    # main.py
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
    from stage1 import Stage1
    from stage2 import Stage2


    s1= Stage1()
    s2= Stage2()

    # S1 to S2 communication
    queueS1 = Queue()  # s1.stage1() writes to queueS1

    # S2 to S1 communication
    queueS2 = Queue()  # s2.stage2() writes to queueS2

    # start s2 as another process
    s2 = Process(target=s2.stage2, args=(queueS1, queueS2))
    s2.daemon = True
    s2.start()     # Launch the stage2 process

    s1.stage1(queueS1, queueS2) # start sending stuff from s1 to s2 
    s2.join() # wait till s2 daemon finishes
```

```py
    # stage1.py
    import time
    import random

    class Stage1:

      def stage1(self, queueS1, queueS2):
        print("stage1")
        lala = []
        lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        for i in range(len(lis)):
          # to avoid unnecessary waiting
          if not queueS2.empty():
            msg = queueS2.get()    # get msg from s2
            print("! ! ! stage1 RECEIVED from s2:", msg)
            lala = [6, 7, 8] # now that a msg was received, further msgs will be different
          time.sleep(1) # work
          random.shuffle(lis)
          queueS1.put(lis + lala)             
        queueS1.put('s1 is DONE')
```

```py
    # stage2.py
    import time

    class Stage2:

      def stage2(self, queueS1, queueS2):
        print("stage2")
        while True:
            msg = queueS1.get()    # wait till there is a msg from s1
            print("- - - stage2 RECEIVED from s1:", msg)
            if msg == 's1 is DONE ':
                break # ends loop
            time.sleep(1) # work
            queueS2.put("update lists")
```

**EDIT**: just found that you can use [queue.get(False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) to avoid blockage when receiving data. This way there's no need to check first if the queue is empty. This is no possible if you use pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Use text files or environnement variables. Since the two run separatly, you can't really do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Using a text file is an idea, but using an environment variable doesn't work between two separate processes or child processes (e.g. two terminals or two python script files). Here's a [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263005/is-it-possible-to-change-the-environment-of-a-parent-process-in-python).

Comment: But using a text file might cause issues when read and write random actions are simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the first script runs to completion, and then the second script runs.  That means you need some sort of persistent state.  Other answers have suggested using text files or Python's `pickle` module.  Personally I am lazy, and I wouldn't use a text file when I could use `pickle`; why should I write a parser to parse my own text file format?

Instead of `pickle` you could also use the `json` module to store it as JSON.  This might be preferable if you want to share the data to non-Python programs, as JSON is a simple and common standard.  If your Python doesn't have `json`, get [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).

If your needs go beyond `pickle` or `json` -- say you actually want to have two Python programs executing at the same time and updating the persistent state variables in real time -- I suggest you use the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database.  Use an ORM to abstract the database away, and it's super easy.  For SQLite and Python, I recommend [Autumn ORM](http://autumn-orm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This method seems straight forward for me:

class SharedClass:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}

def set_data(self, name, value):
    self.data[name] = value

def get_data(self, name):
    try:
        return self.data[name]
    except:
        return "none"

def reset_data(self):
    self.data = {}
```

sharedClass = SharedClass()

PS : you can set the data with a parameter name and a value for it, and to access the value you can use the get_data method, below is the example:

## to set the data

example 1:
sharedClass.set_data("name","Jon Snow")
example 2:
sharedClass.set_data("email","jon@got.com")\

## to get the data

sharedClass.get_data("email")\

## to reset the entire state simply use

sharedClass.reset_data()

Its kind of accessing data from a json object (dict in this case)

Hope this helps....

Answer (score -1):

You could use the basic `from` and `import` functions in python to import the variable into `two.py`. For example:

```
from filename import variable
```

That should import the variable from the file.
(Of course you should replace `filename` with `one.py`, and replace `variable` with the variable you want to share to `two.py`.)

Answer (score -4):

You can also solve this problem by making the variable as global

python first.py

```
class Temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None

global var1
var1 = Temp()
var1.first = 1
print(var1.first)
```

python second.py

```
import first as One
print(One.var1.first)
```

Comment: OP wanted to know how to share a variable between two different _processes_, not how to share between different modules within the same process.