# self._socket.bind(address) File "<string>", line 1, in bind TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using Python 2.6 and trying to start a manager for a given port and authkey

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

    def make_server_manager(port, authkey):
            # ...

        class JobQueueManager(SyncManager):
                pass
        # ...

        manager = JobQueueManager(address=("127.0.0.1", port), authkey=authkey)
        manager.start()

        return manager
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
[hue@sandbox ~]$ python ####.py 5000 abc
Process JobQueueManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 517, in _run_server
    server = cls._Server(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=5)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 106, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 227, in __init__
    self._socket.bind(address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
TypeError: an integer is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    manager = make_server_manager(PORTNUM, AUTHKEY)
  File "####.py", line 145, in make_server_manager
    manager.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 499, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
EOFError
```

Can somebody suggest what to input in the address? It seems it is failing while trying to bind to the address. As the error suggests, how can the address be an integer? Or is it with the port 5000 that I have given at runtime?

A thread on multiprocessing with similar inputs are given for reference:

[How-to-synchronize-a-Python-dict-with-multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545961/how-to-synchronize-a-python-dict-with-multiprocessing)

Comment: It might be dependent on `JobQueueManager`'s `__init__` and its `start`. Can you show them?

Comment: @thefourtheye: It should be using SyncManager `__init__` and `start`. I have added the definition of JobQueueManager in my code already. You can check the implementation from standard SyncManager class of Python 2.6

Comment: You might need `port = int(port)`

Comment: @Max: what I did is totally removed the `sys.argv` and hardcoded the port and authkey. It is work-around for time being