# count how many element have been processed by multiprocessing.Queue by subclass multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to count how many elements have ever been putted into multiprocessing.Queue. my implementation is by subclassing multiprocessing.Queue:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue


class QueueFPS(Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=200):
        self.frame_count = 0
        ctx = multiprocessing.get_context()
        super().__init__(maxsize, ctx=ctx)

    def put(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.frame_count += 1
        print("count in put function: ", self.frame_count)
        super().put(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_count(self):
        print("count in get_count: ", self.frame_count)
```

But when I use this class, I found that the get_count() method always return 0 if I run it with multi process:

```
def worker(test_queue):
    for i in range(2):
        test_queue.put("A")

def test_multi_process():
    test_queue = QueueFPS()
    test_process = multiprocessing.Process(
                    target=worker,
                    args=(test_queue,))
    test_process.start()
    test_process.join()
    test_queue.close()
    test_queue.join_thread()
    print(test_queue.get_count())
```

the out put is:

```
count in put function:  1
count in put function:  2
count in get_count:  0
```

if I run it with only one process, it works as expected, but it will raise a exception(I omit some output of exception)

```
def test_single_process():
    test_queue = QueueFPS()
    for i in range(2):
        test_queue.put("A")
    print(test_queue.get_count())
```

the output is:

```
count in put function:  1
count in put function:  2
count in get_count:  2
None
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
   （I omit some output here）
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*frame_count* is not shared across processes and hence you don't get desired output while using multiple processes. If you try to print

> self.qsize()

which is actually an attribute of the Queue class object you will see the it prints 2.

The reason for this is how Queue is implemented to be thread-safe and process-safe. Here is what Python doc says:

> class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize])
>
> Returns a process shared queue
> implemented using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores. When a process
> first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is started which
> transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.

Since state of the *frame_count* attribute is not synchronised across processes you cant get the desired output.

Comment: I am aware of that multiprocessing.Queue Handle the synchronization between processes. your point is by subclassing it, myown attribute can't benefit from it, I need implement my own synchronization ？

Comment: Yes. Because as per the implementation here [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py]. You need to use threading.Lock and threading.Condition to make sure that your changes are synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

You call the `put` method in a child process. Thus your `put` only changes the `Queue` object that is in that process. The changes do not propagate to the other processes automagically, [you need to take special measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545961/how-to-synchronize-a-python-dict-with-multiprocessing). (`Queue` itself uses a [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Pipe) and custom logic to pass pickled items between processes and that's the only thing that connects its copies.)