# Python: Sending a variable to another script

Tags: python

I'm new to python and kind of been chucked in the deep end at work.

If i had a script which has creates a list such as below:

```
test = 'string'

l = []

for i in test:
    l.append(i)

print l
```

How would i send that this to another python script?

Comment: What do you mean by `this`: the variable l, or the printed representation of it?

Comment: Note that the whole code can be replaced by the much shorter `l = list(test)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use the variable `some_list` defined in a script called `first.py` into a second script called `second.py`

So it would be:

```
$ cat first.py second.py 
#first.py
def demo():
    some_list = []
    for i in 'string':
         some_list.append( i )
    return some_list

#second.py 
from first import demo

some_list = demo()
print some_list 

$python second.py
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

The code in a file is declared as code module. To use it, you have to use:

`from` *module* `import` *thing*

So in this case the function `demo` was defined as a function in the module `first`

In the second file you import it and use it.

You can run arbitrary code in modules and declare variables but it is  better if they are placed in functions ( or classes ) as shown above.

I hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear whether you first script is itself running the second script, or if they are called one after the other by something external. In either case, a simple method to pass the list to the second process is via stdin, where the data itself is a [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) of the list.

For example:

script1.py:

```
import sys
import pickle
list = [item for item in test]
pickle.dump(list, sys.stdout)
```

script2.py:

```
import sys
import pickle
list = pickle.load(sys.stdin)
for item in list:
    print item
```

The run: `script1.py | script2.py`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you mean **sending** the results of the computation to another, separately running Python process, or simply **sharing** that result with another component of a multi-file project.

In the former case, you'll want to use some kind of inter-process communication - some examples are writing the result to a file and reading it from the other process, establishing a socket between the two processes, or using a semaphore.

In the latter case, use Python's concept of [**modules**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) to share the result of this computation with another script in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the Shelve and Pickle modules.  They allow you to serialize data in a way that it can be stored between launches or shared between scripts.

Answer (score 0):

$ cat one.py

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=2048)
class One(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = None

     def set_a(self,val):
         self.a = val

     def get_a(self):
         return self.a


class One_nocache(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = None

     def set_a(self,val):
         self.a = val

     def get_a(self):
         return self.a
```

$ cat two.py

```
import one
import three

# Cache
second=one.One()
second.set_a(4)
three.print_cache()

# No cache
second=one.One_nocache()
second.set_a(4)
three.print_nocache()
```

$ cat three.py

```
import one
def print_cache():
    three=one.One()
    print(three.get_a())

def print_nocache():
    three=one.One_nocache()
    print(three.get_a())
```

$ py two.py

```
4
None
```

> 4 - Is set in three.py by invoking the cached class instance in one.py
>   None - When the same class instance is invoked when the class is not
>   cached.