# python: sending information between two scripts

Tags: python

I have two Python scripts in two different locations and cannot be moved. What is the best way to send information between the two scripts?

say for example in script1.py i had a string e.g.

> x = 'teststring'

then i need variable 'x' passed to script2.py, which saves the variable 'x' to a text file?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "different locations" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just import it.

```
#script2.py
from script1 import x
```

To make the script2 find the script1, the script1 file must be in the [module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

**edit**

Here's an example:

First we create a dir and display the value of the module search path:

```
$mkdir some_dir
$echo $PYTHONPATH
```

It's nothig. Then we create a file with the variable `x` initialized to "hola" in that directory:

```
$cat >some_dir/module_a.py <<.
> x = "hola"
> .
```

And we create another python file to use it:

```
$cat >module_b.py<<.
> from module_a import x
> print x
> .
```

If we run that second script we got an error:

```
$python module_b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module_b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_a import x
ImportError: No module named module_a
```

But, if we specify the *some_dir* in the module search path, and run it again, should work:

```
$export PYTHONPATH=some_dir
$python module_b.py 
 hola
```

Comment: would that work even though the scripts are in two different locations?

Comment: @Peter :) I knew that would be the next question, I was looking the reference. I have updated the answer. For a ( bit ) more complete sample see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066126/python-sending-a-variable-to-another-script/3066158#3066158

Comment: Instead of modifying PYTHONPATH, you might want instead to append the path to some_dir in sys.path, in the program that needs to use the other file.  This would have the advantage of not modifying PYTHONPATH just for a single project.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a socket?

This is a good tutorial about network programming in Python. It includes client/server sample scripts:

http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyNet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard way of doing what you want:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/the_other_module_dir')
import script1

print script1.x
```

In fact, if you modify the environment variable PYTHONPATH for each single project that involves modules that are not in the same directory, you'll have an unnecessarily long PYTHONPATH variable *and* users of your script will also have to modify their PYTHONPATH.  The above canonical method solves these problems.

Alternatively, you might want to directly import `x`:

```
from script1 import x
print x
```