# Remote control functions of a python script running on another computer

Tags: python

So imagine two computers that I have full control on both, I will call them computer A and computer B.

On computer A there is a python script that is running in the background and has multiple functions, one of them being able to create and show a message box: (this is just an example)

```
def msg_box(text,title):
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
    MessageBox(None, text, title, 0)
```

What I want to do, is to access the functions of the script running on computer A from computer B, in the case of the msg_box function, I want to be able to call it on the computer B with any parameters that I want, and it will get executed on computer A. I am a beginner and I don't know how to do this link between the computers, I remind you that I have full control over both of them and they are connected to my local network. Some have suggested me using a ssh server, can someone give me some ideas ?

Comment: You can use a `socket` and communicate.

Comment: Can you give me some tips on how to use sockets for this particular task ? Just for start, I'll go and research more after

Comment: You can look up something like how to make a simple chat server/client with Python. Instead of chatting, you'll just be sending commands.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks, I'll look into that and see what I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [Pyro4 package](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/). Here's an example based on their ["Simple Example"](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#simple-example), with some extra code to start the nameserver automatically and listen over a network.

First use this command on each machine to install Pyro4:

```
pip install pyro4
```

On the server, save this script as `server.py` and then run it in a terminal window via `python server.py`:

```
# saved as server.py
import Pyro4, Pyro4.naming
import socket, threading

# Define an object that will be accessible over the network.
# This is where all your code should go...
@Pyro4.expose
class MessageServer(object):
    def show_message(self, msg):
        print("Message received: {}".format(msg))


# Start a Pyro nameserver and daemon (server process) that are accessible
# over the network. This has security risks; see 
# https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ns_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=Pyro4.naming.startNSloop, kwargs={'host': hostname}
)
ns_thread.daemon = True   # automatically exit when main program finishes
ns_thread.start()
main_daemon = Pyro4.Daemon(host=hostname)

# find the name server
ns = Pyro4.locateNS()
# register the message server as a Pyro object
main_daemon_uri = main_daemon.register(MessageServer)
# register a name for the object in the name server
ns.register("example.message", main_daemon_uri)

# start the event loop of the main_daemon to wait for calls
print("Message server ready.")
main_daemon.requestLoop()
```

On the client, save this as `client.py` and run it with `python client.py`:

```
# saved as client.py
import Pyro4
import sys

print("What is your message?")
msg = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

# lookup object uri on name server and create a proxy for it
message_server = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:example.message")
# call method on remote object
message_server.show_message(msg)
```

Note that setting up Pyro to listen over your network is a security risk. So you should read their [section on security](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html) before you go ahead with this. But this should be enough to get you started.

If you want a solution that just uses the standard library, you could take a look at my socket-based client-server setup in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690818/3830997). Or you might consider setting up a `flask` webserver on the server, and then using `urllib2` on the client to access the server and invoke the correct action (probably via a `GET` or `POST` request). But those are both more difficult than this.

Another option would be to use a different interprocess communication package such as PyZMQ, redis, mpi4py or maybe zmq_object_exchanger. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659789/efficient-python-ipc) for some ideas.

Comment: you're linking to a deprecated location, the correct new location of Pyro4's documentation is here: https://pyro4.readthedocs.io

Comment: Thanks, fixed it!

Comment: almost :)  the 'simple example' and  the 'chapter on security' links still point to the old url.