# why use rabbitmq or similar versus python builtin multiprocessing queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, python-multiprocessing

I have a producer of tasks and multiple workers to consume those tasks. Many places recommend rabbitmq and/or celery. However python has a builtin multiprocessing queue that can be shared on an ip/port using a manager/proxy. What would be the advantages of using something like rabbitmq instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RabbitMq is an enterprise level tool, typically deployed separately on out-of-process servers / VMs / Containers, and plays in the enterprise service bus space.

- Rabbit has reliable messaging as an objective - e.g. messages are persisted, and nodes in the cluster can be restarted without losing messages.
- Supports a large range of [messaging topologies](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html), such as Point-Point, Fan out, and Topic subscriptions
- Can be scaled for volume by adding multiple nodes to a cluster
- Allows for conditional routing of messages to queues using routing keys or header filters
- Agnostic of client technology, i.e. Clients can be on any platform which support the AMQP protocol
- Has an out of the box administration, monitoring and diagnostics UI
- Has a wide range of extensions and tools, such as [shovels](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) allowing messages to be replicated across multiple RabbitMQ clusters.

I'm no Python expert, but from what I understand of the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), it serves as an manager for distributing work between worker processes and threads, so IMO would be regarded as a more local system concern, as opposed to 'enterprise' level.
e.g. you would need to [handle persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9085176/314291), i.e. so messages are not lost during a crash / restart, and would likely need to built your own administration and monitoring tools.