# Update a pymodbus server context while the server is running

Tags: python, client, modbus, pymodbus, slave

I'm currently using a tool called Modbus Slave that worked pretty well with a gui. However, I would like to have some automated tests that's why I would like to use pymodbus. The setup I would like to have with pymodbus is the following :

- **On a STM32 I have a serial modbus master running.**
- **I would like to have two pymodbus slave running with a "data storage", meaning on my Slave ID N°1 I want to have 3100 registers, and on the Slave ID N°248 I want to have 3100 registers for example.**
- **Then, I would like to be able to have my modbus master to write in the data registers of the modbus slave Id N°1 or the Slave ID N°248.**
- Be able to update the context of the Slave ID N°1 for example while it's running.

What's in Bold is working.
As I have not that much experience with python/pymodbus, I would like to know what is the best way to proceed ?

EDIT:

Current code of my pymodbus sync server running with a context of 3100 registers with 0 as default value, for Slave ID 1 and 248.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""

Server sync

"""

from threading import Thread

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.version import version

from pymodbus.datastore import (
    ModbusSequentialDataBlock,
    ModbusServerContext,
    ModbusSlaveContext,
)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the service logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the various client implementations
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from pymodbus.server.sync import (
    StartSerialServer,
)
from pymodbus.transaction import (
    ModbusRtuFramer,
)


def run_sync_server():
    """Run server setup."""
    port = "COM6"
    datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0x00] * 3100)
    context = {
        0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(
            hr=datablock,
        ),
        0xF8: ModbusSlaveContext(
            hr=datablock,
        ),
    }

    # Build data storage
    store = ModbusServerContext(slaves=context, single=False)

    """Run server."""
    txt = f"### start server, listening on {port} - serial"
    print(txt)
    server = StartSerialServer(
        context=store,  # Data storage
        # identity=identity,  # server identify
        timeout=0.01,  # waiting time for request to complete
        port=port,  # serial port
        # custom_functions=[],  # allow custom handling
        framer=ModbusRtuFramer,  # The framer strategy to use
        # handler=None,  # handler for each session
        stopbits=1,  # The number of stop bits to use
        bytesize=8,  # The bytesize of the serial messages
        parity="N",  # Which kind of parity to use
        baudrate=256000,  # The baud rate to use for the serial device
    )
    return server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    server = run_sync_server()
    server.shutdown()
```

Concerning the update_server I have this for now :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# pylint: disable=missing-any-param-doc,differing-param-doc
"""Pymodbus Server With Updating Thread.

This is an example of having a background thread updating the
context while the server is operating. This can also be done with
a python thread::

    from threading import Thread
    Thread(target=updating_writer, args=(context,)).start()
"""
from threading import Thread
import time
import logging
import re
from pymodbus.datastore import (
    ModbusSequentialDataBlock,
    ModbusServerContext,
    ModbusSlaveContext,
)
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartSerialServer
from pymodbus.version import version


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the service logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# define your callback process
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #


def updating_writer(extra):
    """Run for tests
    :param arguments: The input arguments to the call
    """
    print("Check register")
    slave_id = 0x1
    value = context[slave_id].getValues(0x3, 3001, count=1)

    time.sleep(5)
    while value[0] != 0:
        value = context[slave_id].getValues(0x3, 3001, count=1)
        time.sleep(5)
    context[slave_id].setValues(0x6, 1000, [0x10])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    datablock=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, [0x00] * 3100)
    context={
        0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(
            hr=datablock,
        ),
        0xF8: ModbusSlaveContext(
            hr=datablock,
        ),
    }
    store = ModbusServerContext(slaves=context, single=False)

    Thread(target=updating_writer, args=(store,)).start()
```

I had to do lots of fix on pymodbus examples cause they are not up to date with the pymodbus lib (2.5.3).

Comment: I'd suggest using the [synchronous server example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/server_sync.html) as a starting point (you can start by removing unnecessary stuff). The [updating server example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/updating_server.html) will probably also be useful.

Comment: I'll check on this, thanks Brits

Comment: Hey @Brits, I've come up with a synchronous server working as expected with a specific context for two slaves. When discussing between my pymodbus server and my modbus master on my STM32, i can write/read correctly. However, I can't get the updating server to work. I'll put my code in comments, if you can have a look, or if you want to discuss it somewhere else, feel free to tell me where

Comment: It's probably worth raising a new question specifically about the updating server because currently it's not really clear what is not working. I'd probably add a `context[slave_id].setValues(0x3, 3001, [1])` at the loop so the loop will run until the master writes a 0 to the register because currently the thread will terminate in five seconds if nothing is written (for this kind of app I would expect to see an infinite loop running in the thread).

Comment: I saw this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461199/pymodbus-update-context-of-running-server @Brits, I put some comments, but it looks like they found something to work, but I'm not able too, maybe you'll understand it better. Concerning your answer, what do you mean by putting "context[slave_id].setValues(0x3, 3001, [1])" (btw it should be 0x6 for the writing register function of modbus), at the loop ? Like where in the code ? Cause what I see at the end, is the running server context not updated.

Comment: Hello Pierre, have you read [this issue](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/626). It might be related to your problem. Poster says `LoopingCall` works as expected.