# What is the purpose of pipes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I don't have any background on pipes. I saw a Pipe() on line 107 here and I would appreciate if someone could explain what's going on.

Line 107: https://github.com/jcwleo/curiosity-driven-exploration-pytorch/blob/master/train.py

Comment: refere this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463008/python-multiprocessing-pipe-vs-queue

Comment: So at a high level is it just an interface for sending inputs to and outputs from an instance running in a thread?

Comment: Yes, That's accurate!

Comment: It's not meant for inter-thread communication in the _same_ process (would work, but would be overkill, use a `queue.Queue` instead) but between _different_ processes.