# How can I edit and access a variable in one file from multiple other files simultaneously?

Tags: python

I currently have two files: control.py and list.py. list.py contains a list of objects that I want to access and edit in control.py. In the project I'm working on, I should be able to open multiple instances of control.py (essentially, open x number of terminals each running its own instance of control.py). I want to able to access the list in list.py from each instance of control.py. Each instance should be able to edit the list such that after editing, all the other instances should be able to see the edited list.

I've looked into the shelve module but it turns out that shelve doesn't support concurrent modification, so that won't work because i need each instance to simultaneously be able to read and edit the list.

Comment: usually databases can work with many clients at the same time.

Comment: Related: [How to share variables across scripts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829116/how-to-share-variables-across-scripts-in-python)

Comment: @furas what do you mean?

Comment: database servers should support concurrent modification - they always work with many clients which want write at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this problem is known as "pubsub"; i.e., publish/subscribe. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern for a primer on the topic. There is no way to do this using just the capabilities provided by the core Python libraries; at least not without writing a pubsub implementation using those capabilities.

However, I get the sense you are doing the programming equivalent of trying to use a hammer to drive a screw. That is, because a hammer is the only tool you know how to use every problem looks like a nail. Reframing the problem is likely to help you, and us, provide better solutions.