# IPython REPL anywhere: how to share application context with IPython console for future interaction?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, console, ipython, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

IPython console is an extremely power instrument for the development. It used for research in general, application and algorithms developing both as sense catching.

Does there is a way to connect current context of Python app with IPython console? Like `import ipyconsole; ipyconsole.set_interactive_from_here()`.

Here is much more complete situation.

**First flow.**
Below is some sort of running python app with inited DB and web-app route.

```py
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB.new_connection("localhost:27018")
        self.var_A = "Just an example variable"
        
    def run(self):
        self.console = IPythonAppConsole(self) #Console Creation
        self.console.initialize()
        self.kernel = console.start()
        # print(self.kernel.connection_file)
        # << "kernel-12345.json"

    # let the app be some kind of web/flask application 
    @app.route('/items/<item_id>')
    def get_item(self, item_id=0):
        ### GOOD PLACE for
        ### <import ipyconsole; ipyconsole.set_interactive_from_here(self.kernel)> CODE
        item = self.db.find_one({'_id': item_id})
        print(item)
```

**Second interactive flow.** This is a valuable target.

```
$: ipython console --existing "kernel-12345.json"
<< print(self.db.uri)
>> "localhost:27018"
<< print(item_id)
>> 1234567890
```

Does there is a common sense way to implement these two flows? Maybe there is some sort of magic combination of `pdb` and `ipython` kernel?

---

By the way there are another interactive ways to communicate with applications:

1. Debugging. Debug app with pdb/ipdb/web-pdb, using such snipper `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in any line in code.
2. Generate IPython notebook snippet from python code. Anywhere [pyvt](https://github.com/ebanner/pynt).

Today I looking for the answer inside IPython/[shellapp](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/shellapp.py), [kernelapp](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/kernelapp.py) sources with [Jupyter console](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/blob/master/jupyter_console/app.py) and dynamic variable sharing through [Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829116/how-to-share-variables-across-scripts-in-python). Thanks for any kind of ideas!

[image]

Comment: Matthias aka Carreau recommended to start with: [IPython.terminal.embed](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.embed.html) and [embed.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/embed.py) which gives ways to embed either the console; or just the kernel. Some examples are here
[embedding](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/tree/master/examples/embedding) and [Embedding](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/Embedding).

Comment: *from comment*... Those basic examples will block the event loop so the main
application will stop running; there are ways to setup things for
IPython/ipykernel to run on the event loop, or in a thread.

Comment: Did you try `import ipdb` and then  `ipdb.set_trace()`, that should do this for you

Comment: Tarun, yes, I tried it. It's a good way but IPython REPL will be much more interesting for advance research and interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way for you to achieve this is to use ipdb and iPython combo.

```py
x = 2

ipdb.set_trace()

x = 4
```

When you run the code, it drops into a ipdb shell

```sh
❯ python3 test.py
> /Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/opa/test.py(7)<module>()
      5 ipdb.set_trace()
      6
----> 7 x = 4
ipdb>
```

And then you can drop into a `ipython` shell from there

```py
ipdb> from IPython import embed
ipdb> embed()
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan  8 2021, 17:17:43)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: x
Out[1]: 2

In [2]:
```

Comment: Very interesting case. Is it possible to launch `embed()` with creating `kernel.json`? It's useful for future connection from another console like `ipython console --existing`?

Comment: You can try running the same thing I did in ipdb and see if it works

Comment: That works. The result question - how to execute `embed() with kernel` for aside interactive connections. (like `ipython console --existing --shell=60514 --iopub=60515 --stdin=60516 --hb=60517 --key="80f9ec39-4e85d7e97d88fff65cd2ae90"`)

Comment: Final solution: `from IPython import embed_kernel` then call `embed_kernel()` in any code place you want. Yeah!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You want me to update the same in this answer or may be you want to post a new answer?

Comment: Yeah, plz Tarun) - If you update I will check it as the result answer✅. In other case I will write full answer since 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Flask shell is what you are looking for https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/shell/

Comment: Flask shell, Ok! Good point for pushing/poping context.