# Python: how to share an object instance across multiple invocations of a script

Tags: python, object-persistence, object-sharing

I'm use a library which provides a python interface to an external program. This allows me to create:

```
foo = Foo()
```

The code above starts a new instance of the Foo program that I can control from within python.

I have a python scripts which needs to be invoked multiple times and depending on external parameters, tell a single instance of the external Foo program to do different things. Obvious I can't do

`foo = Foo()` everytime,

since that creates a new instance of Foo every time my script runs.

What I want to do is to create `foo= Foo()` once, and have multiple invocations share the same instance. Currently I'm thinkibng of just creating it once, serialize it, and have my scripts deserialize it. Does this approach work? Is there a better alternative?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done if you follow an approach similar to that given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-python-processes). Or you can use [Pyro](http://www.razorvine.net/projects/), which is compared to multiprocessing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171767/comparison-of-the-multiprocessing-module-and-pyro).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). Here's a simple example:

```
import os, pickle

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

# use previous pickled instance if found
if os.path.exists('foo.pickle'):
    with open('foo.pickle') as f:
        foo = pickle.load(f)
else:
    foo = Foo(42)

# print current foo.bar
print foo.bar

# change foo.bar and pickle
foo.bar = raw_input('new bar: ')
with open('foo.pickle', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f)
```

Comment: I tried doing that actually, I got a message saying "Can't pickle 'lock' object: <thread.lock object at ... >". I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Yeah, it has limitations which you may/may not be able to work around to do what you want: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: if you're using a lock, you probably need to take another path like sockets or pipes to provide locked access to your class

Answer (score 0):

You can change the design so that `Foo()` just connects you to an existing process, and then you create a new function, call it `startFoo()` that you previously call once (or if `Foo()` fails). Even better would be to make the program that Foo() connects to a service that you connect to over a socket. You might also want to just switch to the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what i'll have to do seeing as I can't serialize the the Foo object easily.